# Sum of a column in jasper report is not showing value correctly

Tags: jasper-reports

I am taking the sum of a column in which the values are filling from condition but when i take the some of this column it is showing me that amount which is coming without condition for eg

Amount Without condition

- 2
- 3
- 4

sum=9

Amount With Condition

- 3
- 4
- 5

sum=12

it is showing me value 9 instead of  12

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the **Evaluation Time** from **Now** of field sum of coulmn to some thing else such as report.